# USB 3: keyed connector protocol adherence necessary?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

The *USB 2* specification presents the concept of the "Keyed Connector Protocol" in chapter 6 section 2 (6.2). Basically, as I understand it, this **limits the use of type A receptacles to downstream outputs form USB hosts or hubs**. This is how it is meant to be:

```
+-------------------+      +----------+
|                   |      |          |
| Type A Receptacle +------> USB Host |
|                   |      |          |
+-------------------+      +----------+
```

I could not find the topic being picked up in any newer specification like *USB 3.2*. Can I build a **USB device with a type A receptacle** or is this not compliant? This is how I wanna use it:

```
+-------------------+      +----------+
|                   |      |          |
| Type A Receptacle +------> USB Dev. |
|                   |      |          |
+-------------------+      +----------+
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it becasue the USB device can act as a host under some circumstances? It doesn't seem like it will be compliant as you've descibed it, but if you describe why you want this, someone might be able to tell you a compliant way to do that.

Comment: Welll, the reason is, that I want to have one type of connector, but a host in one configuration and a device in another.

Comment: In that case you can do it in a standards-compliant way with a "dual role" or "OTG" connector. The new way to do that is a Type C connector. The old way is a special micro B connector. Type C is better for most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I build a USB device with a type A receptacle or is this not
>   compliant?

You can make a device with Type-A receptacle, but it won't be compliant to any USB specifications. Some early designs of portable HDD enclosures did this, steering confusion among users.

The main reason is that classic USB is a host-centric architecture, so there should be a host that supplies VBUS, and devices that consume VBUS (and/or use VBUS as a signal of "cable connect"). If you make a device, it must be a recipient of VBUS. The USB Type-A connector does not have any extra pins to swap port roles. More, you will need a Type-A-to-Type-A cable, so there will be a possibility that some user will connect this (illegal) cable between two classic hosts, creating VBUS source conflict between two systems and possible damage to ports.

However, there is a rise in demand for devices (mostly mobile) with necessity of having dual role USB ports (formerly known as "OTG", a meaningless term). So the industry is moving towards the dual-role functionality and truly universal connector, and the means to provide this is the **USB Type-C connector**. The legacy Type-A and Type-B connectors are systematically depreciated across the set of USB specifications. I would strongly advise to forget the idea of using Type-A on a device, and seriously consider Type-C instead.